# Java Anti Aliasing to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-resizing, antialiasing

I am trying to convert the following code to Java:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(iconFile)

image = image.convert('L').resize(
    (9, 8),
    Image.ANTIALIAS,
)
```

-->

```
BufferedImage picture = ImageIO.read(new File(iconFile));

int IMG_WIDTH = 9;
int IMG_HEIGHT = 8;

BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();

g.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
```

How do I perform the anti aliasing operation? My app is a command line tool which scales images.

Comment: Let me guess, you were implementing dhash in java? Is your implementation open source by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to do this too. I found that the Java default image rescale operations were not suitable for downsizing image and left a low quality finish.

In the end I started to use [the java-image-scaling library](https://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/). Its very good and easy to use and provides a very good finish.

A sample usage would be:

```
ResampleOp  resampleOp = new ResampleOp (100,200);
BufferedImage destImage= resampleOp.filter(sourceImage, null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks amazing after resizing with that lib. :)